# How can I optimize omp pragmas to run code between parallel regions?

Tags: c, performance, openmp

I have this C code that I need to optimize with OpenMP, I can't write the original code, but here is a surrogate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif

void Funct(double *vec, int len)
{
    int i;
    double tmp; 
    //Section 1
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )    //Code that initialize vec, it simulates an initialization in the original code
        vec [ i ] = i; 

    //Section 2
    //This code must be run sequentially
    tmp = vec [ 0 ];
    vec [0 ] = vec [ len - 1 ];
    vec [ len - 1 ] = tmp;

    tmp = vec [ 0 ];
    vec [0 ] = vec [ len - 1 ];
    vec [ len - 1 ] = tmp; 
    //End of the sequential code 

    //Section 3
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )    //Code to simulate loadwork on vec
    {
        vec [ i ] = pow(vec[i], 2 ); 
        vec [ i ] = sqrt ( vec [ i ] );
        vec [ i ] += 1;
        vec [ i ] = pow(vec[i], 2 ); 
        vec [ i ] = sqrt ( vec [ i ] );
        vec [ i ] -= 1;
    }

}

int main ()
{
    double *vec;
    int i;
    vec = (double *) malloc ( sizeof ( double ) * 5104 );  //Length of the vector in the original code

    for ( i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )    //Iteration in the original code 
        Funct(vec, 5104 );

    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )      // Access the array to avoid -O2 cancellations
    printf ("%.2f ", vec [ i * 1000 ] );
    return 0;
}
```

In Funct, Section 1, 2 and 3 must be executed sequentially; Section 2 is strictly sequential.

In the original code I'm forced to use parallelization inside the function Funct(...), so, sadly, the cost of the creation of the threads are multiplied by the number of iterations, but is not a problem since it still permits some time optimization when the for inside the main or the vec length arise ( If you have suggestions I'm very open to listen ). The problem is "Section 2", in fact it makes OMP, I think, create a barrier or a wait, but that slows down the execution; If I remove that section I get a pretty acceptable optimization, respect to the sequential code; saddly I can't.
I've tried omp single, omp critical, and so on, to see if it would have assigned the code to some of threads of the prvious pool, but none, is there a way to make more performant? ( Like drastically change the pragmas, not a problem )

( Compiled with gcc file.c -o file.out -lm -O2 -fopenmp, tested under Linux Lubuntu using time ./file.out )

**Edit 1:**
I'd like to point out that

```
tmp = vec [ 0 ];
vec [0 ] = vec [ len - 1 ];
vec [ len - 1 ] = tmp;

tmp = vec [ 0 ];
vec [0 ] = vec [ len - 1 ];
vec [ len - 1 ] = tmp;
```

Is just random code I've put inside the method to make clear that must be run sequentially ( it performs two time the same operation, it swaps vec [ 0 ] and vec [ len - 1 ], so at the end of the execution nothing really happend );
I could have written any other function or code instead;

For instance I could have put

```
Foo1();
Foo2();
Foo3();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your loop indices to

```
for ( i = 1; i < len-1; i++ )
```

and treat the first and last elements as special cases. They can be executed outside of the OpenMP regions.

Comment: Thanks for the quickness bud! I will improve my question; Section 2 is a random code inside the function, the original code is different, so, to make it clearer, instead of "tmp = vec [ 0 ] ... " I could have written any other generic function or code that is forced to run sequentially, for instance Foo1(); Foo2(); Foo3();

Comment: @U.Manuel: But can you predict which elements these operate on? Or how many elements are affected?

Comment: Yes, I can ( in the original code ); I know how may will be affected and they can be parallelized, but they have a poor "parallelization ratio" because they are a small amount. But before your question I haven't thought that maybe using an omp parallel for, even with that small amount of elements, the thread pool would be preserved and performance less affected.
Thank you @Richard, I'll let you know!

Comment: Ok, just tested out, no improvements... The three section must be independent, because they calculate important data for the next section which requires all the vector to be calculated. The only exception is Section 2, which uses only a part of the original vector, but it has a very low number of elements compared to the length of the vector itself.

Comment: @U.Manuel: It'd be nice if there was a better MWE for the problem. In OpenMP each iteration of the loop must be independent of the others. Since Section 3 uses the same memory as Sections 1 and 2, each iteration in 3 must be independent. Therefore, if you know what elements are specially affected by 2 ahead of time, you should be able to remove them from Loop 3. If you can remove them from 3, then you can merge Loops 1 and 3. And do the operations 2 and 3 on the special elements after Loop 3 finishes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit barrier at the end of a parallel section. A way to improve the code would be to enclose all the function into a `#pragma omp parallel` directive, so that threads are spawned only once at the beginning rather than twice at sections 1 and 3.

The implicit barrier will still be there at the end of the `omp for` loops, but this is still less overhead than spawning new threads. Section 2 would then have to be enclosed in an `omp single` block (this may well be what you have done as you mention that *omp single* did not work better, but it is not 100% clear).

```
void Funct(double *vec, int len)
{
    // Create threads
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        //Section 1
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
            //Code that initialize vec, it simulates an initialization in the original code
            vec [ i ] = i; 
        } // Implicit barrier here (end of omp for loop) 

        //Section 2
        //This code must be run sequentially
        // It will start only once the section 1 has been completed
        #pragma omp single
        {
            double tmp;

            tmp = vec [ 0 ];
            vec [0 ] = vec [ len - 1 ];
            vec [ len - 1 ] = tmp;

            tmp = vec [ 0 ];
            vec [0 ] = vec [ len - 1 ];
            vec [ len - 1 ] = tmp;
        } // Implicit barrier here (end of omp single block) 
        //End of the sequential code 

        //Section 3
        #pragma omp for
        for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )    //Code to simulate loadwork on vec
        {
            vec [ i ] = pow(vec[i], 2 ); 
            vec [ i ] = sqrt ( vec [ i ] );
            vec [ i ] += 1;
            vec [ i ] = pow(vec[i], 2 ); 
            vec [ i ] = sqrt ( vec [ i ] );
            vec [ i ] -= 1;
        } // Implicit barrier here end of for
    } // Implicit barrier here end of parallel + destroy threads
}
```

The best would be to move the `omp parallel` directive to the `main` function, so that threads are spawned only once.

Comment: Hey, Believe it or not, but by timing the executions the solution I've put into the question has the best performance, it runs about 7 seconds faster than the solution you provided and a lot faster than putting the omp parallel inside the main ( which has the worst execution time ).
Timings are 37,261 seconds, 44.609 seconds and the last more than  a minute and a half ( I stopped it because it was taking too much respect to the others )

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this is interesting. I would have thought that thread initialization would consume much overhead - and I don't really understand why a barrier take more overhead than stopping and starting again the threads.